# Automatically sync new files from google drive to google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I want to automatically sync new files that are added to google drive to google cloud storage.
I have seen various people asking this on the web and most of them suggest something along the lines of:

- Develop an app to poll for new files in the drive
- Retrieve new files and upload them to GCS

If someone has already written an open-source library/script for this then I would like to reuse it instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Edit:

I have now written a watcher webhook API in python, and subscribed to the folder to get notification when a new file is added to google drive.
Now the issue is, when the webhook is called by Google, no information is provided about the new files/folders added.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking for a method to sync content on different services( NFS, Disks, etc ) to GCS in order to have a backup there and make data accessible to applications which can only access to the cloud storage buckets.

We don't have a google owned solution for this however we have several partners [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage#:%7E:text=Backup%2C%20archival%2C%20and%20disaster%20recovery) which offer proprietary solutions which might work for your usecase.

Comment: I tried the link, but I couldn't find any details on the partners providing a solution to move data from drive to cloud storage